# How to export jupyter notebook as markdown?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter-lab

Dear python developers,
I have trouble with exporting my notebook as markdown with jupyter-lab, while I can export it as a markdown file with Jupiter notebook. I've searched a lot on the net but I can't solve it, can anybody help me to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Most likely you just have nbconvert out of sync with your current JupyterLab or some other package that is being used for that behind the scenes. One work around would be to install [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) and use that on the command line to convert your notebook. See the command `jupytext --to markdown notebook.ipynb` listed [here](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html#command-line-conversion). You can use the command in a notebook in the same directory as you work with the notebook to convert by using `!jupytext --to markdown notebook.ipynb`.

Comment: Given [this recent issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/11885) and other similar ones, I suspect `jupyter-server` that will need to be updated in the environment where you installed JupyterLab.